# How to integrate a "shortcode" feature in Sharepoint wikis

Tags: sharepoint

I would like to "customize" my sharepoint wiki by doing something very simple.

I would like to be able to run a regex on wiki pages looking for `[math]` and `[\math]` tags, then take the expression written in the middle (assume this value is stored in a variable `x`) and replace the whole block by

```
 "<img src='http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?" + x +"'/>"
```

So for example, the shortcode [math]a^2+b^2=c^2[\math] should end up being displayed as an image as follows (thanks to [this online tool](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php)):

[image]

I have never developed anything in sharepoint, and I've been using it for a week.

Can anybody tell me how I should proceed to add such a feature (if it's possible)?

Answer (score 4):

You can use existing solution like [ShortPoint](http://shortpoint.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Sure - this is simmply done via two methods - 1) You could modify the page directly using SharePoint designer - fly in the code where you want it, 2) The better way - add your code to text file, upload the text file to a document library then use the Content Editor web part, drop it on the page, point it (through the properties) to the text file.

Note: The Content Editor part will allow you to modify the background HTML/Script, however, it has a nasty habit of overriding your code and I've had it actually duplicate itself (adding repeat scripts). Using the Text file eliminiates that issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not sure I understand how I should proceed with the content editor. Could you point out to an example or a good tutorial?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the ContentEditor solution would imply using Javascript right? Not a server-side code. If I want to do this using C# for example, I would have to use the Sharepoint Designer is that it?

Comment: Add Content Editor part, select Properties - set the file path to the text file you uploaded - include <script></script> in the JS and you are good to go. NOTE: This works much better than the Script part.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, I don't think that the content editor web part is the solution you are looking for.  I believe you are wanting to implement a shortcodes solution such as that found in WordPress, correct?  In that case, the issue becomes a bit more complex.  To really get any kind of custom code that would execute at the necessary stages, you would need a custom solution either implementing additional functionality in the existing rich text editor, or roll your own custom rich text editor.

At that point, you would have complete control over how the content is parsed and interpreted, so you could have both server-side and client side processing.  You could make use of templating engines like mustache or handlebars.

To do this, you would need to write your own Custom field type, inherit from SPFieldMultiLineText, override the property FieldRenderingControl, and return your custom control.  That way you have the option of implementing it in several different places (custom pege fields in a page layout, custom webparts, custom lists, etc.) and you still get the benefits you want from the out-of-the-box control.